# How to calculate difference in time from the same column grouped by another column?

Tags: excel, time, powerpivot, difference, powerquery

I have an excel power query (also added to powerpivot data table) with two fields: Location and OpenedTime. Location column has many duplicates such as this example:

```
Location     OpenedTime
LOC_1        9/25/2016 1:48:56 AM
LOC_2        9/30/2016 2:01:00 PM
LOC_1        10/10/2016 12:08:00 PM
LOC_3        9/17/2016 9:35:43 PM
LOC_1        10/15/2016 11:14:21 AM
LOC_2        10/16/2016 8:27:34 PM
LOC_3        10/18/2016 11:52:27 AM
LOC_2        10/22/2016 9:09:00 AM
```

What I am looking for is a way to calculate the difference in open time for the 3 locations.

So a new column would display the difference between 10/10/2016 12:08:00 PM and 9/25/2016 1:48:56 AM for LOC_1.

Since there are multiple timestamps to calculate differences of, I was thinking if it would be possible to average all differences into one average difference for each LOC

Thank you!!

Comment: It is possible using DAX. The logic would be, compare each timestamp against the previous to get the difference, then sum those differences in seconds and get the average. is that right for you? Just try it if you get stuck I'll post an answer.

Comment: I thought of the same logic however I cant wrap my head around how to tell excel to specifically calculate time differences from the same location. I reckon a possible way would be to use the if and match formula?

Comment: Do you know about DAX in PowerPivot? I can think in a DAX expression to do what you need, but I can't tell you how to do it using Excel formulas.

Comment: Yes, I have used DAX several times. I just cant figure out the expression I would need to use to achieve this. I would really appreciate your help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can do to get the desired result:

Add a new column to your PowerPivot table using this DAX expression:

```
Previous Date=
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( [OpenedTime] ),
    FILTER (
        TableName,
        EARLIER ( TableName[OpenedTime] ) > [OpenedTime]
            && EARLIER ( TableName[Location] ) = [Location]
    )
)
```

This expression get the previous date against you should calculate the difference for each row, note that if there is no a previous date it left it BLANK.

Then add a second calculated column to your PowerPivot table to calculate the difference in `Minutes`:

```
Diff (Min)=DATEDIFF([Previous Date],[OpenedTime],MINUTE)
```

If you want to calculate the difference in hourse just replace MINUTE by HOUR or DAY or SECONDS, etc.

It will give you a column with the difference then you can just calculate the average easily by creating a measure:

```
Avg OpenedTime (Min) := AVERAGE(TablaName[Diff (Min)])
```

Let me know if this helps.